# When clicking on a new node in the tree, how to get the old node?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm looking at the [TreeView events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview_events(v=vs.110).aspx) and not seeing it.

For example BeforeSelect shows the new node:

```
private void myTreeView_BeforeSelect(Object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string node = "\tNode: " + eventArgs.Node; // This is the new node
    string action = "\tAction: " + eventArgs.Action; // ByMouse
    string cancel = "\tCancel: " + eventArgs.Cancel; // False
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by using `((TreeView) sender).SelectedNode`

```
private void myTreeView_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string node = "\tNode: " + eventArgs.Node; // This is the new node
    string action = "\tAction: " + eventArgs.Action; // ByMouse
    string cancel = "\tCancel: " + eventArgs.Cancel; // False

    //Get the current selected node/old node after the select processed
    var oldNode = ((TreeView) sender).SelectedNode;
}
```